# AOS appears to not be working correctly with Animate.css + mdboostrap

Tags: html, css, animate.css, mdbootstrap, aos.js

I'm currently making a portfolio site for myself, but it appears to be broken in a way that I do not understand; oddly enough I cannot get AOS and Animate.CSS to work on the website. I am hosting on GitHub pages (yes, I included a .nojekyll file). Hosted locally and on GitHub pages both show nor errors in the console:

Console Photos (Sorry, not enough reputation!!)  [image]

Here is a link to the latest code (via GitHub):

https://github.com/FxllenCode/fxllencode.dev/blob/main/index.html

I do not know what might be causing it, some help would really be appreciated here! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the issue, oddly enough it did not work using AOS so I went back to wow.js and found that the docs are inaccurate for both libraries as they do not work with the latest version of animate.css. I was able to fix it by writing it as a `wow animate__animated animate__bounce` instead of the described `wow bounce`. Interesting issue, looks like they both need to update their docs.